# How to deal with a non existing session variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I am trying to check if a booking record exists, then show its details. Otherwise return to `Bookparking` page but else part isn't working and shows `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` because there is no such field with the `Session[""]`

Controller:

```cs
public ActionResult Viewparking()
{
   if (IsUserLoggedIn(Session, Request) == false)
   {
       return RedirectToAction("login");
   }
   else
   {
       String id = Session["username"].ToString();
       ViewBag.userid = id;
       var checkbooking = db.tb_booking.Where(s => s.username == id).FirstOrDefault();
       if (checkbooking != null)
       {
           var show = db.tb_booking.Where(e => e.username == id).FirstOrDefault();
       }
       else
       {   //ViewBag.f = "You have no booking yet!!";
           return RedirectToAction("Bookparking", "user");
       }
       return View();
   }
}
```

Comment: check first `Session["username"]` if it has value, you cannot `.ToString()` null objects and I believe that is the reason of error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Yes spotted !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gabriel noted, you have not null checked the value from the session. Code would be something like this:

```
public ActionResult Viewparking()
{
    if (IsUserLoggedIn(Session, Request) == false)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("login");
    }
    else
    {
        String id = Session["username"]?.ToString();
        if (id != null)
        {
            ViewBag.userid = id;
            var checkbooking = db.tb_booking.FirstOrDefault(s => s.username == id);
            if (checkbooking != null)
            {   // TODO: checkbooking is currently unused, except to check if you can fetch it.
                return View();
            }
        }
        // If you reach this code, then either id is null, or the booking was not found
        return RedirectToAction("Bookparking", "user");
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `string id = (string)Session["username"];`